# how to pass parameter to open modal dialogue box in bootstrap using jsp?

Tags: jsp, bootstrap-modal

I want to open modal dialogue box in bootstrap by passing parameter in jsp. when user clicks on button dialogue box must be opened.

```html
<a data-id="+subid+" type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>View Order</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want if a parameter is passed to the jsp the button Appear

```
     <% String msg2=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("NAME-PARAM");%>

    <% if ( (msg2==null || msg2.isEmpty()) ) { %> 
       //WHAT YOU WANT

                             <% } else if(msg2!=null) { %>

<a data-id="+subid+" type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>View Order</a>
                            <% }  %>
```

and in the servlet set the parameter :

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("NAME-PARAM",PARAMETER);
```